# VBA Excel — Start macro if criteria met

Tags: vba, excel

I have recorded a macro which I want to fire only if **C1** has a specific text. The issue is that **C1** is a mixed of text and numbers. So while text is permanent, numbers are always different. I want something that reads only the text of C1, and if text criteria met, the macro below should come into action, or else it should do nothing. The permanent text block of **C1** is **DFM:** (followed by some figures) i.e, **DFM: 34,493.27**

Secondly, is there a better macro to achieve what the recorded macro does?

```
Sub AddDeci()
Range("C2:D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.000"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsNumeric(Replace([C1], "DFM: ", "")) Then
        Range([C2], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row, "D")).NumberFormat = "#,##0.000"
    ElseIf Not (Replace([C1], "DFM: ", "")) Then
        Range([C2], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row, "D")).NumberFormat = General
    End If
End Sub
```

put the code inside sheet
[image]

Comment: Vasily will it only see if the **C1** has a numeric value or not? I want it to see if the text **DFM:** exists, disregarding numericals. **C1** will always be alphanumeric. I want the macro to fire ONLY if **C1** starts with the text **DFM:** .  Thanks for the quick help :)

Comment: @MunirAbrar, you can just replace the text, but principle will be the same, see my updated post

Comment: Thank you very much Vasily, it does the job :)